How to set SSL CA for Docker Desktop in Windows
I am trying to set up Docker Desktop in my Windows PC. The company firewall is intervening the network connections, thus docker server is rejecting my connection.
PS C:\Users\maldemir001> docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/hello-world/manifests/latest": Get "https://auth.docker.io/token?account=mustafaaldemir649&scope=repository%3Alibrary%2Fhello-world%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io": EOF.
See 'docker run --help'.

I was having the same problem with AWS CLI an Git. I solved it by adding AWS_CA_BUNDLE environment variable and setting http.sslCAInfo configuration.
Does Docker have such an option in Windows too?

https://forums.docker.com/t/add-ca-certificate-ssl-inspection-for-the-docker-egine/137891

Is there an option I can do as a non-admin user?
